# OD Cost Matrix (arcpy) Layer Not Added

Tags: arcpy, layers, network-analyst

I'm trying to create a OD Cost Matrix layer programmatically.  The problem that I have, however, is that the layer doesn't get added to my Table of Contents.

If I manually run the Network Analyst->Analysis->Make OD Cost Matrix Layer tool a new layer is created in my Table of Contents; however, trying to accomplish the same from arcpy yields no layer.

Likewise, I'm trying to programmatically download, extract, and symbolize OSM (OpenStreetMaps) data.  When utilize this OSM tool programmatically a new layer is not added to my Table of Contents.

Here is the relevant code from my toolbox.

```
# Load the OpenStreetMap toolbox.
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\OpenStreetMap Toolbox.tbx")

##
# Get the window extents.
##

# This is the current map, which should be an OSM base map.
curMapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

# Get the datafrom from the map (see the DataFrame object of arcpy).
# The DataFrame object has an "extent" object that has the XMin, XMax, YMin, and YMax.
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(curMapDoc, "Layers")[0]
extent    = dataFrame.extent

messages.addMessage("XMin: {0}, XMax: {1}, YMin: {2}, YMax: {3}".format(extent.XMin, extent.XMax, extent.YMin, extent.YMax))

# Download the data from OSM.
# The "OSMLayer" layer does not get added!
arcpy.DownloadExtractSymbolizeOSMData2_osmtools(extent, True, "OSM_SAC_TEST", "OSMLayer")

##
# Convert the OSM data to a network dataset.
##
arcpy.OSMGPCreateNetworkDataset_osmtools("OSM_SAC_TEST", r"DriveGeneric.xml", r"ND")

###
# Create the OD Cost Matrix layer.
###
#network = "OSM_SAC_TEST_ND"
network = r"C:\Users\avejidah\Documents\ArcGIS\DB\ImportTest.gdb\OSM_SAC_TEST\OSM_SAC_TEST_ND"
# The "OD Cost Matrix" layer does not get added!
arcpy.na.MakeODCostMatrixLayer(network, "OD Cost Matrix", "DriveTime")
```

I don't get any error or anything, the tool runs and says "Completed."  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured it out.  I just needed to get the resulting layer and add it.

```
result = arcpy.na.MakeODCostMatrixLayer(network, "OD Cost Matrix", "DriveTime")
layerObj = result.getOutput(0)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataFrame, layerObj, "BOTTOM")
```